# LinkedList, memory overflow for vector constructor?

Tags: c++

This code add Two sum integer using linkedList.
I have added to the *struct ListNode* a new constructor in order to give him as input two vectore A and B.

```
      ListNode(vector<int> array)
      {
        vector<int>::iterator itr = array.begin();
      ListNode *t = nullptr;
        for (; itr < array.end(); itr++) {
            t->val = *itr;
            t = t->next;
        }
      }
```

This is a strange overflow ??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
/*
  Definition for singly-linked list.
*/
  struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
      
      ListNode(vector<int> array)
      {
        vector<int>::iterator itr = array.begin();
      ListNode *t = nullptr;
        for (; itr < array.end(); itr++) {
            t->val = *itr;
            t = t->next;
        }
      }
      
  };
 
class Solution {
public:
    Solution(){};
    
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode *p = l1;
        ListNode *q = l2;
        ListNode *dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode *current = dummyHead;
        int carry = 0;
        
        while (p != NULL || q != NULL) {
            int x = (p != NULL) ? p->val : 0;
            int y = (q != NULL) ? q->val : 0;
            int sum = carry + x + y;
            carry = sum / 10;
            
            current->next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            current = current -> next;
            
            if (p != NULL) {
                p = p -> next;
            }
            
            if (q != NULL) {
                q = q -> next;
            }
        }
        
        if (carry > 0) {
            current -> next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return dummyHead->next;
        
    }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Solution *sol = nullptr;
    vector<int> A = {2,4,3};
    vector<int> B = {5,6,4};
    ListNode *list1= new ListNode(A);
    ListNode *list2= new ListNode(B);

    sol->addTwoNumbers(list1,list2);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Use case for test:

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

Comment: No, you are just trying to dereference a `nullptr`. Take a close look at `t` in `ListNode(vector<int> array)`.

Comment: Thanks. not works also without initializing `t` with `nullptr` !

Comment: @SaïdBENAISSA I don't think you understand, you must initialise `t` by making it point to some memory (by using `new`), Not initialising it and initialising it to `nullptr` are both wrong.

Comment: Also, you should use `next` somehow, otherwise this constructor will leave that uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListNode` constructor is not creating a new `ListNode` for `t` to point at before you access `t->val`.  It is also not even attempting to initialize the members of `this`.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
struct ListNode {
    int val = 0;
    ListNode *next = nullptr;

    ListNode(int x = 0, ListNode *next = nullptr) : val(x), next(next) {}
      
    ListNode(const vector<int> &array)
    {
        if (!array.empty()) {
            auto itr = array.begin();
            val = *itr++;
            ListNode **t = &next;
            while (itr != array.end()) {
                *t = new ListNode(*itr++);
                t = &((*t)->next);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

That being said, having such a constructor in `ListNode` really makes no sense.  A list node should only care about its own data, not about the data of the nodes around it.  This kind of list construction really belongs in a separate `List` class that wraps a chain of `ListNode`s, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

/*
  Definition for singly-linked list.
*/
  struct ListNode {
      int val = 0;
      ListNode *next = nullptr;
      ListNode(int x = 0, ListNode *next = nullptr) : val(x), next(next) {}
  };
 
  class List {
  private:
    ListNode *head = nullptr;

  public:
      List() = default;

      List(const vector<int> &vec)
      {
          ListNode **t = &head;
          for (int val : vec) {
            *t = new ListNode(val);
            t = &((*t)->next);
        }
      }

      List addNumber(const List &l) const {
          ListNode *p = head;
          ListNode *q = l.head;
          List dummyList;
          ListNode** current = &(dummyList.head);
          int carry = 0;
        
          while (p || q) {
              int x = (p) ? p->val : 0;
              int y = (q) ? q->val : 0;
              int sum = carry + x + y;
              carry = sum / 10;
            
              *current = new ListNode(sum % 10);
              current = &((*current)->next);
            
              if (p) {
                  p = p->next;
              }
            
              if (q) {
                  q = q->next;
              }
          }
        
          if (carry > 0) {
              *current = new ListNode(carry);
          }

          return dummyList;
      }

      // what follows is stuff needed for compliance with the "Rule of 3/5/0":
      // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

      List(const List &list)
      {
          ListNode **t = &head;
          for(ListNode *n = list.head; n; n = n->next) {
            *t = new ListNode(n->val);
            t = &((*t)->next);
        }
      }

      List(List &&list)
      {
          std::swap(head, list.head);
      }

      ~List()
      {
          ListNode *n;
          for (ListNode *t = head; t; t = n) {
              n = t->next;
              delete t;
          }
      }

      List& operator=(List rhs) {
          List temp(std::move(rhs));
          std::swap(head, temp.head);
          return *this;
      }
  };

class Solution {
public:
    List addTwoNumbers(const List &l1, const List &l2) {
        return l1.addNumber(l2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Solution sol;
    vector<int> A = {2,4,3};
    vector<int> B = {5,6,4};
    List list1(A);
    List list2(B);

    List result = sol.addTwoNumbers(list1, list2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all. (The only need for constructor. for me, just to initialize inputs (l1, l2) directly at instantiation in main.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing a null pointer that's why you get the memory error. You have to initialize it and allocate memory. Here you initialize `ListNode *t = nullptr;`. So `t` is referencing as `NULL` pointer. Next, you here dereferencing `t->val = *itr;` but `t` is pointing to `NULL`.

Try something like this for singly-linked list.

```cpp
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};
```

Then your main task is to create a link list from a vector, for this you can use a class that holds the vector link list. And another requirement is to add to the vector link list. So we can create a vector link list in reverse order. And for this, you can use this code snippet.

```
class VectorList {
public:
    ListNode *root;
    VectorList() : root(nullptr){}
    VectorList(vector<int> &array){
        root = new ListNode();
        ListNode *curr;
        curr = root;
        int _size = array.size();
        for(int i = _size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            ListNode *t = new ListNode(array[i]);
            curr->next = t;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        root = root->next;
    }
};
```

So now we can create two vector lists and then add the vector lists and print the desired answer. And for this, you can use this code snippet.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* curr, *root = NULL;
        int carry = 0;
        while(l1 || l2){
            if(l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l1->val + l2->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l1->val + l2->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l1 = l1->next;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            else if(l1 == NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l2->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l2->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            else if(l2 == NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l1->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l1->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
        }
        if(carry){
            ListNode* t = new ListNode;
            t->val = carry;
            t->next = NULL;
            curr->next = t;
        }
        return root;
    }
    void print(ListNode *root){
        ListNode *curr = root;
        while(curr){
            cout << curr->val << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

So overall, here is the main code with the desired output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/*
  Definition for singly-linked list.
*/

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};

class VectorList {
public:
    ListNode *root;
    VectorList() : root(nullptr){}
    VectorList(vector<int> &array){
        root = new ListNode();
        ListNode *curr;
        curr = root;
        int _size = array.size();
        for(int i = _size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            ListNode *t = new ListNode(array[i]);
            curr->next = t;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        root = root->next;
    }
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* curr, *root = NULL;
        int carry = 0;
        while(l1 || l2){
            if(l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l1->val + l2->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l1->val + l2->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l1 = l1->next;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            else if(l1 == NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l2->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l2->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            else if(l2 == NULL){
                ListNode* t = new ListNode;
                t->val = (l1->val + carry) % 10;
                t->next = NULL;
                carry = (l1->val + carry) / 10;
                if(root == NULL){
                    curr = root = t;
                }
                else{
                    curr->next = t;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
        }
        if(carry){
            ListNode* t = new ListNode;
            t->val = carry;
            t->next = NULL;
            curr->next = t;
        }
        return root;
    }
    void print(ListNode *root){
        ListNode *curr = root;
        while(curr){
            cout << curr->val << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Solution *sol = nullptr;
    vector<int> A = {2,4,3};
    vector<int> B = {5,6,4};
    VectorList list1 = VectorList(A);
    VectorList list2 = VectorList(B);
    ListNode *root = sol->addTwoNumbers(list1.root, list2.root);
    sol->print(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
```

Sample Output:

```
[7 0 8]
```

Comment: Thanks @Badhan. Before i have created constructors for testing the program for given use case. But i have to create my test use case by giving him arrays as input. Thank you